# How To Make spcefic Cell In Telerik Grid Display Message Contains Rows Information

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

How To Make specific Cell In Telerik Grid () Display Message Contains Rows Information..
Example :

```
Id   Name LastName Telephone 
1    jo    jol       098
2    mo    mol       987
3   fo    fol       394 
4    do    doo       234 
5    me    mee       245
```

when i clicked on cell that have id=3  ..i need to Display message Contains " Name:fo LastName:fol Telephone:394 ) 
and When I clicked on cell that have id=1 or 2 or 4 or 5 .. i need to Nothing happen ..

Comment: do you use `RadWindowManager` ?

Comment: yes bet what is the different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet. Let me know if any concern.

**ASPX** (For Row Click)

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script>
        function RowClick(sender, args) {
            // I have used ColumnUniuqName 
            var id = args.get_item().get_cell("ID").innerHTML;
            var Name = args.get_item().get_cell("Name").innerHTML;
            var Contact = args.get_item().get_cell("Contact").innerHTML;

            if (parseInt(id) == 3) {
                alert("Name:-" + Name + ",Contact:-" + Contact);
            }
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" UniqueName="ID" HeaderText="ID">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Contact" UniqueName="Contact" HeaderText="Contact">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings>
        <ClientEvents OnRowClick="RowClick" />
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

**ASPX** (For Cell Selected)

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script>
        function CellSelected(sender, args) {
            // I have used ColumnUniuqName 
            var row = sender.get_masterTableView().get_dataItems()[args._itemIndexHierarchical];
            var id = row.get_cell("ID").innerHTML;
            var Name = row.get_cell("Name").innerHTML;
            var Contact = row.get_cell("Contact").innerHTML;

            if (parseInt(id) == 3) {
                alert("Name:-" + Name + ",Contact:-" + Contact);
            }
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" UniqueName="ID" HeaderText="ID">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Contact" UniqueName="Contact" HeaderText="Contact">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings>
        <Selecting CellSelectionMode="Column" />
        <ClientEvents OnCellSelected="CellSelected" />
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Contact", typeof(int));

    dt.Rows.Add(1, "name1", 123);
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "name2", 456);
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "name3", 789);

    RadGrid1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: thanks .. Run Correctly .. but how i can ensure if the cell selected from column Id ?